# When I run this code it does not display any result from the query

Tags: php, database, pdo

The query does not produce any results. The variable response is supposed to hold the query result but  when I test it contain using  var_dump it shows that it is empty.

```
 try
 {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ems', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e)
 {
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
 }
 $code=123456;

 $query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Code,sender FROM info WHERE Code = ?');
 //,reciever,origin,destination,transit
 $query->execute(array($code));
 if($query->fetchColumn())
 {
     echo"good";
     while($reponse = $query->fetch()){
         var_dump($reponse);

         echo"good";
         echo $reponse['sender'];
     }

   } else{
     echo" The Code entered  was not  found please verify and  enter again";
 }
```

Comment: Run your query directly in the SQL shell. Any results?

Comment: Check that `$query->execute` comes back true. If it does not, use `$bdd->errorInfo` to see what is wrong.

Comment: Do you get "good" printed out? If so, it's probably because `fetchColumn` consumes the row you are intending to read.

Comment: Check your braces. I noticed that you have 5 braces, which means that something wasn't closed correctly.  (Are you missing a closing brace for your `if` block??

Comment: Please how  to i check that $query->executecomes back true

Comment: `echo($query->execute(array($code))?"yes":"no");`.  Did you directly run your SQL yet?  If not, don't do anything until you do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was simply a typo in your code, but I noticed this block of code:

```
if($query->fetchColumn())
{
    echo"good";
    while($reponse = $query->fetch()){
     var_dump($reponse);

     echo"good";
     echo $reponse['sender'];
    }

else{
 echo" The Code entered  was not  found please verify and  enter again";
}
}
```

Looking at your code (and your comment), you have an open brace `{` for the `if` statement, followed by an open brace for the `while` loop. Then there is a closing brace.  The closing brace `}` is for the `while` loop. Then you have an pair of braces for the `else` block. You also have another `}` after the `else` block. Try adding a `}` before your `else` block and remove one of the `}` after the `else` block. The `else` block should not be nested in the `if` block (if I understand you completely).  This is a syntax error.

How the code should look:

```
if($query->fetchColumn())
{
    echo"good";
    while($reponse = $query->fetch()){
     var_dump($reponse);

     echo"good";
     echo $reponse['sender'];
    }
}
else{
 echo" The Code entered  was not  found please verify and  enter again";

}
```

Comment: it is a typo error cuz  my codes have two  close }} after the else

Comment: Ok edit your original question. However, that's still a syntax error. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.